# convertir columnas y sumarlas hacer una columna nueva de consumo total

Tags: python

Debes utilizar Pandas para ingestar en un objeto Dataframe el contenido del archivo provisto
"Fuentes_Consumo_Energia.csv".
El ExaJulio es una unidad diferentes al TWh, es decir, no tiene sentido sumarlos o
buscar proporciones entre ellos, la fórmula de conversión es:
277.778 Teravatios/Hora (TWh) = 1 Exajulio
Los campos terminados en "_EJ" corresponden a mediciones en Exajulios,
y los terminados en "_TWh" corresponden a Teravatios/Hora.
La consigna es crear un nuevo campo, que se denomine "Consumo_Total"
y que guarde la sumatoria de todos los consumos expresados en Teravatios/Hora
(convirtiendo a esta medida los que están en Exajulios)
Esta función debe informar el consumo total para la entidad 'World' y año '2019',
redondeado a 2 decimales, retornando ese valor en un dato de tipo float.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score -1):

df = pd.read_csv("datasets\Fuentes_Consumo_Energia.csv")
df4 = df.copy()

```
df4['consumo_total'] = (df4['Coal_Consumption_EJ'] * 277.778) + (df4['Gas_Consumption_EJ'] * 277.778) + (df4['Oil_Consumption_EJ'] * 277.778) 



res4 = df4[(df4['Entity'] == 'world')& (df4['Year'] == 2019)]



res4 = round(res4.iloc[0],2)
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hola Hugo, bienvenido, las respuestas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad, siempre tratamos de explicar como nuestra respuesta resuelve el problema planteado, te sugiero que la edites, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos.